# AWS on Ubuntu WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, aws

I'm using Ubuntu WSL and I installed AWSCLI but since it's also installed on Windows, Ubuntu throw an error since it's trying to use the Windows version one...

> /mnt/c/Users/jonathan.lafleur/web objects  aws --version zsh:
>   /mnt/c/Program Files/Python36/Scripts//aws: bad interpreter:
>   c:\program: no such file or directory  ✘ 
>   /mnt/c/Users/jonathan.lafleur/web objects  where aws /mnt/c/Program
>   Files/Python36/Scripts//aws

But I know AWS is installed since I got this message :

> Successfully installed PyYAML-5.1 awscli-1.16.207 botocore-1.12.197
>   colorama-0.3.9 docutils-0.14 futures-3.3.0 jmespath-0.9.4 pyasn1-0.4.5
>   python-dateutil-2.8.0 rsa-3.4.2 s3transfer-0.2.1 six-1.12.0
>   urllib3-1.25.3

If I echo my path :

> echo $PATH
>   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common
>   Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/PHP/v5.3:/mnt/c/Program Files/Python36/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/Python36/:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/PuTTY/:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Users/jonathan.lafleur/AppData/Roaming/nvm:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Druide/Antidote
>   9/Application/Bin64/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Druide/Antidote
>   9/Application/Bin32/:/mnt/c/Users/jonathan.lafleur/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/WebStorm/ch-0/173.4548.30/bin:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Too:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance
>   Toolkit/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/Microsoft VS
>   Code/bin:/mnt/c/nodejs/:/mnt/c/PHP/7.1:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files
>   (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components/DAL:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files/PowerShell/6/:/mnt/c/Users/jonathan.lafleur/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/jonathan.lafleur/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin:/mnt/c/MinGW/bin:/mnt/c/Program
>   Files (x86)/FontForgeBuilds

Any idea how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Windows & Linux Interopability, you can disable it through flags or conf files, here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51345880/435514